# Boost converter - low inductance and discontinuous or high inductance and continuous?

Tags: noise, boost, converter

I'm working on a battery powered application and I need to step up from ~3v to ~25V.  I'm trying to balance the peak battery loads vs the overall performance.
[image: 3572 circuit]

I'm torn on the inductor.  I'm at ~2MHz operation and if I set it to 15uH the system runs continuous and the peak battery current is roughly ~275mA due to turn on (basically charging C2).  However, if I set it to 2.2uH the system runs discontinuous and the peak input current is down to ~195mA, basically due to the cycle-by-cycle peak current in the switch terminating some of the cycles early.
Here's the real question - is there a downside to the discontinuous operation?  Am I going be generating more noise (electrical, magnetic or audible; inductor will be "shielded")?  Will I be stressing anything here that would cause an early failure?

Comment: You haven't mentioned load (full range) and regards current you just appear to be talking about inrush. Nothing to really go on to help you.

Comment: DC mode will create a little more EMI and have more voltage ripple compared to CM.

Comment: It's just running a couple piezos, call it ~100mA average with significant dynamic content